# 2010 VW Golf MAPS sensor issue/car won't start

Tags: engine-start

Brought my car in to deal with the check engine light.  The mechanic told me it was a problem with the MAPS sensor, which we got him to replace.  The car worked fine for one day following the repair.

The following day, the car wouldn't start.  Here is list of my observations:

1. The car cranks for about a second, then stops cranking and starts making a clicking noise.
2. The car is able to start with a jump.
3. The battery seems fine, as all other electrical systems related to the car work properly (wipers, radio, lights, etc.)
4. I can restart the car within 30 seconds of turning it off.  If I wait any longer than that, then it won't start.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your battery may be bad, you need to test the charging system, if the charging system is good, replace the battery.

If the alternator is not charging then you need to diagnose that first, more than likely the alternator is faulty and needs replacement.

Comment: I'll take the battery in to get it tested to rule it out as the cause of the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: You still need to test the charging system.

Comment: Got the battery checked (before going through an entire check of the charging system) and the cell was dead.  Replaced the battery and it works fine now.  Thanks for the help stranger!